# c# timer Always enabled Performance

Tags: c#, system.timers.timer

I would like to have a timer running 100% of the day and was unsure if this would cause an issue. It will tick once a minute for the most part and will compare DateTime.Now to 5 stored values.

In theory does having this timer running mean i will be taking a performance hit once per minute, or is the minimal code involved going to create a problem.

Comment: Computers can perform millions operations per second. Comparing current time with 5 `DateTime` values every minute will not cause performance issues...

Comment: Even if not necessary in this case, a good practice is disabling the timer at start of event handler code and reenabling it at end of event handler.

Comment: So Tick once per minute, Run the handler ( a delegate function ) and then re-start the timer? wont this create a gap of However long the delegate takes to finish execution? meaning each tick will be maybe 1 minute and 1 second? @Graffito

Comment: @ModS that wrote "meaning each tick will be maybe 1 minute and 1 second" : Indeed. But, timers ticks are not really the best approach for operations requiring a precise timing.

Comment: @graffito what is the reason to stop the timer? Like what happens if i just let the timer always run with out ever stopping it

Comment: If the process in the timer takes too long, you will get more events that can be processed. In an application, using many timers in different forms, it may be difficult to precisely evaluate the total process time used by all the timers and be sure that the application frequently enters in idle state for processing UI events in reasonable delays.

Answer (score 1):

There won't be enough code to have any noticeable performance hit.  The timer executes the code in one or more event sinks and will use a minimal amount of CPU cycles.

Comment: Thanks, I really need to keep time and was hoping that this constant "timer" being enabled may weigh in on the performance. I appreciate it :)

Comment: How do you plan to use the comparison data? How accurate of a comparison do you need?

Comment: im making a "reminder" section in my application. the user fills out some fields, a reminder "appears" in their "reminders" area. Once its time for the Reminder to display a message it will display whatever message the user chose. 
I was hoping to be able to remind the user in the same minute that they specified but seconds are not important to me

Comment: @ModS Instead of firing once a minute to see if there are any reminders to show why not make one timer per reminder and have its duration be the time between the time you create it and the time it is supposed to go off.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I was scared to go that route due to "un-forseen" issues, such as users restarting the application, switching sessions such as "locking their computer", however now that i look at it this may just be a more efficient route. are there any possible issues you can think of that i may need to program against?